# Cannot see all my functions when running Open CPU single-user server

Tags: rstudio, roxygen2, opencpu

When I run `ocpu_start_app("my_package")` not all the functions are displayed and I cannot access those that are not listed, although they are under the `my_package/R/` folder as the OpenCPU documentation states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it seemed to be an issue with roxygen2. This package creates the documentation and the NAMESPACE file that OpenCPU uses. For some reason, roxygen2 wasn't executing automatically when I built my package from RStudio (Ubuntu 18.04). So I had to run manually roxygen2. You can do this in several ways:

From roxygen2 documentation:

`roxygen2::roxygenise()`, or

`devtools::document()`, if you’re using devtools, or

`Ctrl + Shift + D`, if you’re using RStudio.

After this, I just had to rebuild my project and relaunch the OpenCPU single server and all started working again.